# How to make VSCode continue search for modules to import under debugging when having several packages under same namespace

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I have a Python project where I depend on another Python package I develop.

Call them 'moduleA' and 'moduleB'.
Both are distributed as Python packages.

I have given the packages a namespace where the company name is the top level. i.e. 'companyA.moduleA' and 'companyA.moduleB'.

In my repo (for moduleB), I have a 'src' layout:

```
projectB
├── build
│   └── venv
├── .env
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── src
│   └── companyA
│       └── moduleB
│           ├── classB.py
│           └── __init__.py
└── tests
```

For debugging I make a virtual environment under the build folder.
In that venv, I have installed the dependency moduleA with pip.
So, I can use 'from companyA.moduelA import classA' in moduleB code.

But, when I debug moduleB in VSCode, I fail to import from moduleA because it looks in the folder 'src/companyA' for 'moduleA', and does not look into the site-packages folder of the venv.

Is it possible to configure VSCode so that if it does not find 'moduleA' under 'src/companyA', then search under 'companyA' in the venv site-packages?

PS! I am running with Python v3.11+

PS2! When installing both packages in a virtualenv, it works (since both are installed under the same namespace). The problem is when debugging in VSCode.

Comment: BTW, I do have a file '.env' on the root level of the repo that says:

     PYTHONPATH="./src"

Comment: I suspect that the root cause here might be related to Python caching imported modules.

So that an early import of a class in my development project (say 'from companyA.moduleB.fileB import fileClassB') will mask the 'companyA' from the site-packages folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure why it did not work for me.
But, clearing any caches that I could find, selecting another Venv temporarily, and finally, reselecting my working Venv solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shortcuts **"Ctrl+Shift+P"** and type **"Python: Select Interpreter"** to choose the virtual environment.

Otherwise you can explicitly [set the Python interpreter in `launch.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_python) when debugging via the setting for your debug config.

Comment: Thanks. I already had the correct virtual env set.
It was still not working, but after some filing and restart of VSCode, it just started working.
I will try to summarize what I did in a separate answer.